# Primefaces DataTable fires update THREE times

Tags: datatable, primefaces, getter, updating

In the code shown below the button with `update="testTable"` fires `Bean.getSensors` call  **three** times, but the button with `update="@form"` fires only one. Why?

```xml
<h:form id="form4" prependId="true">
    <p:commandButton value="id" update="testTable" process="@none"/>
    <p:commandButton value="@form" update="@form" process="@none"/>

    <p:dataTable id="testTable" value="#{bean.sensors}"
                    var="sensor"
                    rowStyleClass="#{sensor.alarm ? 'alarm' : null}">
        <p:column headerText="Name" style="min-width: 100px; width: 100px;">
            <h:outputText value="#{sensor.name}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Value" style="min-width: 100px; width: 100px;">
            <h:outputText value="#{sensor.value}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. JSF and Primefaces need to call it multiple times.
If You have performance issues, use lazy loading

```
 public List<Sensor> getSensors(){
    if(sensors == null){
       sensors = ejb.getSensors();
    }
    return sensors;
 }
```